# changing header font in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I'm designing a personal blog using ruby on rails (ruby version 2.6.6)

I've tried using this [guide](https://medium.com/@maloriecasimir/css-custom-fonts-for-your-rails-app-7163299bb41f) to change the font of the heading in the homepage of my web site. I've added the font I want in `app\assets\fonts` and I've added the following code:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "orangejuice";
   src: url('/assets/fonts/orangejuice.ttf')
}
```

I've added the aforementioned code into the file 'app\assets\stylesheets\welcome.scss`

and I've also added in the file `\node_modules\serve-index\public\style.css` the lines:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: "orangejuice";
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happened, and I don't have any other `.css` files which I can edit.

What could be the problem? Why don't I see a change in my app? the file `application.css` is empty, there's no other code in it.

In general, I'm having trouble with understanding how to change the design of my site using rails, I've looked at many guides, but I can't find anything which explains all the options I have for designing my site. Perhaps anyone have an advise about what should I read?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By adding this snippet:

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: "orangejuice";
   src: url('/assets/fonts/orangejuice.ttf')
}
```

To your `welcome.scss` file, it will only by accessible in that file.

So what you can do is remove the code above and put it in your `application.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "orangejuice";
  src: url(asset-path("orangejuice.ttf"));
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: "orangejuice";
}
```

In this way it will be globally applied.

Comment: Thank you vary much for your comment. I followed your advice, and now I can control the size of the header, but the font still won't change. perhaps you have any idea why it still doesn't work?

Comment: I tried the snippet i gave you on a Rails app and it works fine. Check your console in the developer tools, it might give you more information on your problem. I suspect that your font file name is not the correct one.